# Trying to subprocess blender. Crashes on startup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, blender

I try to run blender from a c++ project with a python script. For this I use `_popen`. It crashes on startup with an `blender is not responding`-error though.

I have some subfolders where the .exe for my program gets generated and Visual Studio is configured to have the relative path start at this location. That looks like this:

```
Debug
|--- MyProgram.exe
|
|--- blender-2.72b-windows64
|
|--- Resources
|    |--- GenericHeadMesh.blend
|
|--- python
|    |--- global.py
|    |--- local.py
|
|--- Output
```

I build a string for the command (making the relative paths absolute).

The functions for getting the absolute paths (this is rather sloppy, but it is not meant to be
shipped, it's a study project).

```
std::string PathHandler::GetBlenderPath()
{
    if (blenderPath.empty())
        blenderPath = GetFullPath(R"(blender-2.72b-windows64\)");
    return blenderPath;
}

std::string PathHandler::GetOutputPath()
{
    if (outputPath.empty())
        outputPath = GetFullPath(R"(Output\)");
    return outputPath;
}

std::string PathHandler::GetResourcesPath()
{
    if (resourcesPath.empty())
        resourcesPath = GetFullPath(R"(Resources\)");
    return resourcesPath;
}

std::string PathHandler::GetPythonPath()
{
    if (pythonPath.empty())
        pythonPath = GetFullPath(R"(python\)");
    return pythonPath;
}

std::string PathHandler::GetFullPath(const std::string relPath)
{
    char full[_MAX_PATH];
    _fullpath(full, relPath.c_str(), _MAX_PATH);
    return EscapeString(std::string(full));
}

std::string PathHandler::EscapeString(const std::string input)
{
    std::regex toReplace("\\\\");
    std::string output(input.begin(), input.end());
    output = std::regex_replace(output, toReplace, "\\\\");
    return output;
}
```

My subprocressing function looks like this (with some debugging):

```
void PythonConnector::runCommand(const std::string &command)
{
    FILE* output = _popen(command.c_str(), "r");
    qDebug() << "c_str(): " << command.c_str();
    qDebug() << _pclose(output);
}
```

I'm building strings like this:

```
std::string blenderPath = pH.GetBlenderPath() + "blender.exe";
std::string meshGlobalPath = pH.GetResourcesPath() + "GenericHeadMesh.blend";
std::string pythonGlobalPath = pH.GetPythonPath() + "global.py";
std::string globalCommand = "\"\"" + blenderPath + "\" --background \"" + meshGlobalPath + "\" --python \"" + pythonGlobalPath + "\" -- \"" + pH.GetOutputPath() + "\"\"";
```

The first and the last quote are for the string obviously, each path again has an escaped quote to catch paths with spaces and I had to put another escaped quote at the begin and the end because otherwise it wouldn't even start blender (or try at least).

I need to subprocess blender twice after another (apply some changes, store result, calc with these changes and apply that again), so I need
some way of subprocessing that actually waits for the subprocess to finish like _popen does.

A path would look like this (the debug from `runCommand()`):

> c_str():  ""C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\QtTest\x64\Debug\blender-2.72b-windows64\blender.exe"
>   --background "C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\QtTest\x64\Debug\Resources\GenericHeadMesh.blend"
>   --python "C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\QtTest\x64\Debug\python\global.py" --
>   "C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\QtTest\x64\Debug\Output\""

_pclose() gives an exit code of 0 (would be 1 without the additional ").

(A debug of just `globalCommand` would start and end with three quotes, but the debug with c_str() only does with two.

Now what this does is trying to launch blender and then just crash with a `blender is not responding` message.
If I debug, I get a source at msvcr120.dll and an exit code of 3. (Which can mean either that the path wasn't found or that there was not enough memory which isn't the case according to the task manager.) I can't get further information of this, the .pdb for this can't be loaded.

If I type an equivalent command in the cmd prompt by hand it works just fine. That looks like this:

> "C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\QtTest\x64\Debug\blender-2.72b-windows64\blender.exe"
>   --background "C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\QtTest\x64\Debug\Resources\GenericHeadMesh.blend"
>   --python "C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\QtTest\x64\Debug\python\global.py" --
>   "C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\QtTest\x64\Debug\Output\"

I have no idea what is causing this problem. Is it some rights my programm doesn't have? I can write data to .txt files in the `Output`-folder without a problem.

I am using blender 2.72b, Visual Studio 2013 and Windows 7 64bit.

Edit:
Seems like the problem is related to the project/it's settings/something. I created a new project as test and this works perfectly fine:

```
std::string command = "\"\"C:\\Users\\Gunnar\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\QtTest\\x64\\Debug\\blender-2.72b-windows64\\blender.exe\" --background \"C:\\Users\\Gunnar\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\QtTest\\x64\\Debug\\Resources\\GenericHeadMesh.blend\" --python \"C:\\Users\\Gunnar\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\QtTest\\x64\\Debug\\python\\global.py\"  -- \"C:\\Users\\Gunnar\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\QtTest\\x64\\Debug\\Output\\\"\"";
FILE* f = _popen(command.c_str(), "r");
_pclose(f);
```

I have no idea what is causing this problem. I changed some settings e.g. where the relative path starts. I've reverted that, but it didn't change anything. I guess I will create a new project and copy stuff over. The project seems to have some problems in general. It became very slow at some point and laggs the computer from time to time (giving that little checking icon).

Comment: To test, hard-code the entire string instead of trying to programatically build it.  If it doesn't work with a hard-coded string, then it isn't going to work if you're writing a program to build the string.

Comment: I did some hard-code tests, I'm not quite sure though if it was with this "state". Might have been with two quotes only, need to test that tomorrow. In an even earlier version (hard-coded, not quotes for spaces, raw string literal, no additional paramter that is passed to the python script) it was working so it should be possible to do this. That was  written on another computer, but that should not be a problem since blender is running just fine when executed as normal program.

Comment: Ok, it seems like it is actually a problem related to the solution. I created a new solution with just a main file to test this and it works. Spaces are a problem though. There has to be a problem in the project settings I guess. I noticed that it got very slow a some point (in VS) like lagging the computer and giving that little checking icon at the bottom. I have no idea what is causing that (and if that is related to this problem). I think I will try to create a new, empty project and copy stuff over.